# Reading a column value in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My df looks like:

```
ID     IntakeDate Quantity Converge
6001   3-Jul-52       WB        T
6001  17-May-57       WB        F
6001   3-Jul-52       AD        T
6001  17-May-57       AD        F
```

I want to read the 'Converge' column for IntakeDate == '3-Jul-52' and Quantity =='WB'. Here's my code:

```
df_1 = df.loc[(df['IntakeDate']=='3-Jul-52')]
df_2 = df_1.loc[(df_1['Quantity']=='WB')]
convergence = df_2.loc[df_2,'Converge']
```

Is there a better or easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain conditions with `&` for `bitwise AND` or `|` for `bitwise OR`:

```
df_1 = df.loc[(df['IntakeDate']=='3-Jul-52') & (df['Quantity']=='WB'), 'Converge']
```

Or use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df_1 = df.query("IntakeDate=='3-Jul-52' & Quantity=='WB'")['Converge']
```

---

```
print (df_1)
0    T
Name: Converge, dtype: object
```

Comment: `df.loc[(df['IntakeDate']=='3-Jul-52') & (df['Quantity']=='WB'), 'Converge'].item()` or `df.loc[(df['IntakeDate']=='3-Jul-52') & (df['Quantity']=='WB'), 'Converge'].iloc[0]`

Comment: I think there are possible 3 ways of output, so better is use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45756722/2901002) solution.

Comment: and instead `a = df.loc[df['Col 1'] == a, 'Col 2']` use `a = df.loc[(df['IntakeDate']=='3-Jul-52') & (df['Quantity']=='WB'), 'Converge']` or `a = df.query("IntakeDate=='3-Jul-52' & Quantity=='WB'")['Converge']`